# Prove that $\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $l_\infty$ be the vector space of bounded sequences of real numbers. Let $\|\mathbf{x}\|=\sup_{n\ge 1}|x_n|$. Prove that $\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$.

**My attempt:**

Let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\in l_\infty$. Then $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ x_2,\ \ldots)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,\ y_2,\ \ldots)$. $\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}=(x_1+y_1,\ x_2+y_2,\ \ldots)$

$\|\mathbf{x}\|=\sup_{n\ge 1}|x_n|\implies |x_n|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|\ \forall n\ge 1$

$\|\mathbf{y}\|=\sup_{n\ge 1}|y_n|\implies |y_n|\le\|\mathbf{y}\|\ \forall n\ge 1$

$\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|=\sup_{n\ge 1}|x_n+y_n|\implies |x_n+y_n|\le\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|\ \forall n\ge 1$

$|x_n+y_n|\le|x_n|+|y_n|\ \forall n\ge 1$ (Triangle inequality)

But $|x_n|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|$ and $|y_n|\le\|\mathbf{y}\|\ \forall n\ge 1$

So, $|x_n+y_n|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|\ \forall n\ge 1$

So, $\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$ is an upper bound for $|x_n+y_n|$. --------------- (1)

So, $\sup_{n\ge 1}|x_n+y_n|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$

$\Leftrightarrow\|\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}\|\le \|\mathbf{x}\|+\|\mathbf{y}\|$

QED

Comment: Is this even true?  What if $\mathbf{x} = (1,0,1,0,1,0,\dots)$ and $\mathbf{y} = (0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots)$?

Comment: Am I missing something? Take any not-constantly-zero sequence $(x_n)$ and put $y_n = -x_n$; doesn't this provide an immediate counter-example to equality? Where did you see this claim?

Comment: What if $\mathbf{y}=-\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ is nonzero?

Comment: Oops...I fixed the question.

Comment: @Callus you're talking about $\limsup$. I think. In any case, the OP's definition of $\sup$ is correct.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Thanks, complete brain fart.  Erased to avoid further confusion.

Comment: It looks right, or simply:   $$\sup_n |x_n + y_n| \leq \sup_n (|x_n| + |y_n|) \leq \sup_n |x_n| + \sup_n |y_n|$$